# Copy output value to another sheet when the range input changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have three scenarios of input range ("A1&C3") it can be F1&H3/ J1&L3 /N1&P3.
When I change value of A1&C3 to one of three scenarios, the value in A10&C12 also change (because it contains formula).

[image]

I don't want to copy each output result ("A10& C12") to another sheet of three scenarios manually.

I tried to use VBA to make it automatically (3 outputs in 3 new sheets).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Save()
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1&C3").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1&H3").Value Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1&C3").Copy
        Worksheets("BC").Range("A1&C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1&C3").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J1&L3").Value Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1&C3").Copy
        Worksheets("UB").Range("A1&C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1&C3").Value = Worksheetss("Sheet1").Range("N1&P3").Value Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1&C3").Copy
        Worksheets("LB").Range("A1&C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your "ranges" aren't valid range format. A1:C3.

Comment: Use `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value` instead of copy paste. This is but an example.

Comment: Use the worksheets change event.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your arrays are wrongly notated within that Range field. Should be A1:C3 and likewise throughout your ranges.
2. You can't use "Value" as an array comparison in this method. Unless you convert the entire array to a single string and then compare it, its likely going to require some for loops to iterate thru the arrays... that's just a lot of ugly code.

Understanding that when you select a A1:C3, you're creating a you're creating an indexed array or "variant" as they're called in the "land of VB"... needless to say, here's some tweaks that just iterate throughout each of the cells and perform comparative operations for each column/row value and then determine if there's a reasonable match.

Or you could just concatenate it as one big string like this...

```
For col = 0 To 2 'For Each Column (3 columns)
    For Row = 0 To 2 'For each row (3 rows)
        'These variable declarations are simply going to append the "Alphabetical" character representation
        Z = Chr(Delta + col) & (Row + 1)
        A = Chr(Comp1 + col) & (Row + 1)
        B = Chr(Comp2 + col) & (Row + 1)
        C = Chr(Comp3 + col) & (Row + 1)
        1starraystr = 1starraystr & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Z).Value 
        2ndarraystr = 2ndarraystr & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(A).Value
        3ndarraystr = 2ndarraystr & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(B).Value
        4ndarraystr = 2ndarraystr & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(C).Value
    Next
Next
if 1starraystr = 2ndarraystr then... ' you get the idea.
```

You could compare strings like that afterwards. It's cheeky but could be cleaner than counting a variable upwards. Up to you.. I'll present both options.

```
Sub Save()
    'Set the numeric DEC value for each letter to easily iterate thru alphabet / array comparison.
    Const Delta = 65, Comp1 = 70, Comp2 = 74, Comp3 = 78
    'Set Counters to 0 to just use a simple counter to validate accuracy of 3 matches.
    C1 = 0: C2 = 0: C3 = 0
    For col = 0 To 2 'For Each Column (3 columns)
        For Row = 0 To 2 'For each row (3 rows)
            'These variable declarations are simply going to append the "Alphabetical" character representation
            Z = Chr(Delta + col) & (Row + 1)
            A = Chr(Comp1 + col) & (Row + 1)
            B = Chr(Comp2 + col) & (Row + 1)
            C = Chr(Comp3 + col) & (Row + 1)
            'Debug.Print Z & vbTab & A & vbTab & B & vbTab & C
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Z).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(A).Value Then C1 = C1 + 1 ': Debug.Print C1
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Z).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(B).Value Then C2 = C2 + 1 ': Debug.Print C2
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Z).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(C).Value Then C3 = C3 + 1 ': Debug.Print C3
        Next
    Next
    'Debug.Print "C1 Count: " & C1
    'Debug.Print "C2 Count: " & C2
    'Debug.Print "C3 Count: " & C3
    If C1 <= 9 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C3").Copy
        Worksheets("BC").Range("A1:C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        'Debug.Print "Copied Cells to BC"
    ElseIf C2 <= 9 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C3").Copy
        Worksheets("UB").Range("A1:C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        'Debug.Print "Copied Cells to UB"
    ElseIf C3 <= 9 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C3").Copy
        Worksheets("LB").Range("A1:C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        'Debug.Print "Copied Cells to LB"
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```